# MUI persistent drawer nav bar breaks for a particular route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to the MUI library. I've managed to build a nav bar and it works fine for one route (Dashboard). But for the candidate route it collapses as shown : [Screengrab of candidate route where the nav bar collapses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5F3s.png)

Screen grab of the dashboard route where the nav bar doesn't break :
[Screen grab of Dashboard route where nav bar renders as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQB3x.png)

**Drawer code:**

```
import { styled, useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Drawer from "@mui/material/Drawer";
import MuiAppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Divider from "@mui/material/Divider";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";
import ChevronLeftIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ChevronLeft";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight";
import ListItemIcon from "@mui/material/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import MenuList from "@mui/material/MenuList";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import PersonIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Person";
import DashboardIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Dashboard";
import LogoutIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Logout";

import { NavLink, withRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Routes from "./Routes";

const drawerWidth = 240;

const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "open",
})(({ theme, open }) => ({
  transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
  }),
  ...(open && {
    width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    marginLeft: `${drawerWidth}px`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(["margin", "width"], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
    }),
  }),
}));

const DrawerHeader = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
  // necessary for content to be below app bar
  ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  justifyContent: "flex-end",
}));

const PersistentDrawerLeft = (props) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);

  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const activeRoute = (routeName) => {
    return props.location.pathname === routeName ? true : false;
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <AppBar position="fixed" open={open}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            edge="start"
            sx={{ mr: 2, ...(open && { display: "none" }) }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap component="div">
            Welcome!
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        sx={{
          width: drawerWidth,
          flexShrink: 0,
          "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
            width: drawerWidth,
            boxSizing: "border-box",
          },
        }}
        variant="persistent"
        anchor="left"
        open={open}
      >
        <DrawerHeader>
          <img
            src={require("../images/icon.jpg")}
            alt="icon"
            style={{ height: "70px" }}
          />
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            {theme.direction === "ltr" ? (
              <ChevronLeftIcon />
            ) : (
              <ChevronRightIcon />
            )}
          </IconButton>
        </DrawerHeader>
        <Divider />
        <MenuList>
          {Routes.map((prop, key) => {
            return (
              <NavLink
                to={prop.path}
                style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "gray" }}
                key={key}
              >
                <MenuItem selected={activeRoute(prop.path)}>
                  <ListItemIcon>
                    {prop.sidebarName === "Dashboard" ? (
                      <DashboardIcon />
                    ) : prop.sidebarName === "Candidate" ? (
                      <PersonIcon />
                    ) : (
                      <LogoutIcon />
                    )}
                  </ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText primary={prop.sidebarName} />
                </MenuItem>
              </NavLink>
            );
          })}
        </MenuList>
        <Divider />
      </Drawer>
      <Switch>
        {Routes.map((route) => (
          <Route exact path={route.path} key={route.path}>
            <route.component />
          </Route>
        ))}
      </Switch>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default withRouter(PersistentDrawerLeft);
```

**Candidate form:**

```
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import FormLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormLabel";
import RadioGroup from "@material-ui/core/RadioGroup";
import Radio from "@material-ui/core/Radio";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

import BasicDatePicker from "./BasicDatePicker";
import BasicSelect from "./BasicSelect";

const defaultValues = {
  name: "",
  email: "",
  age: 0,
  gender: "",
  mobile: "",
  currentCompany: "",
  currentCtc: "",
  expectedCtc: "",
  status: "",
};
const NewCandidateForm = () => {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(defaultValues);
  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormValues({
      ...formValues,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
  };
  return (
    <Box
      component="form"
      sx={{
        "& .MuiTextField-root": { m: 1, width: "25ch" },
      }}
      
      
    >
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Grid
          container
          direction="column"
          spacing={1} 
          
        >
          {/* Name field */}
          <Grid item>
            <TextField
              id="name-input"
              name="name"
              label="Name"
              type="text"
              value={formValues.name}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </Grid>
          {/* Date of Birth */}
          <Grid item>
            <BasicDatePicker />
          </Grid>
          {/* Gender */}
          <Grid item>
            <FormControl>
              <FormLabel>Gender</FormLabel>
              <RadioGroup
                name="gender"
                value={formValues.gender}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              >
                <FormControlLabel
                  key="male"
                  value="male"
                  control={<Radio size="small" />}
                  label="Male"
                />
                <FormControlLabel
                  key="female"
                  value="female"
                  control={<Radio size="small" />}
                  label="Female"
                />
                <FormControlLabel
                  key="other"
                  value="other"
                  control={<Radio size="small" />}
                  label="Other"
                />
              </RadioGroup>
            </FormControl>
          </Grid>
          {/* Email */}
          <Grid item>
            <TextField
              id="email-input"
              name="email"
              label="Email"
              type="email"
              value={formValues.email}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </Grid>
          {/* Mobile */}
          <Grid item>
            <TextField
              id="mobile-input"
              name="mobile"
              label="Mobile"
              type="number"
              value={formValues.mobile}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </Grid>
          {/* Status select */}
          <BasicSelect />
          {/* Current Company */}
          <Grid item>
            <TextField
              id="currentCompany-input"
              label="Current Company"
              name="currentCompany"
              type="text"
              value={formValues.currentCompany}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </Grid>
          {/* Current CTC */}
          <Grid item>
            <TextField
              id="ctc-input"
              label="Current CTC"
              name="currentCtc"
              type="number"
              value={formValues.currentCtc}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </Grid>
          {/* Expected CTC */}
          <Grid item>
            <TextField
              id="ectc-input"
              label="Expected CTC"
              name="expectedCtc"
              type="nuber"
              value={formValues.expectedCtc}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Button
            className="SubmitFormButton"
            variant="contained"
            style={{ width: "250px", alignItems: "center", marginTop: "20px" }}
            type="submit"
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </form>
    </Box>
  );
};
export default NewCandidateForm;
```

**Rotue:**

```
import React from "react";
import NewCandidateForm from "./NewCandidateForm";
import BarChart from "./BarChart";
import StackedChart from "./StackedChart";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const roleData = {
  count: [2, 3, 4, 10, 4, 3, 3, 2],
  categories: [
    "AL2",
    "SAL1",
    "SAL2",
    "SDE1",
    "SDE2",
    "SDE3",
    "Specialist Mgr",
    "Sr. Specialist Mgr",
  ],
  titleText: "Role coverage",
  color: "#CB5757",
};

const spocData = {
  count: [2, 3, 4],
  categories: ["Data1", "Data2", "Data3"],
  titleText: "SPOC",
  color: "#CF9152",
};

const sourceData = {
  count: [2, 5, 1, 7, 5, 4, 8, 3, 4, 7, 2, 1, 5],
  categories: [
    "Data1",
    "Data2",
    "Data3",
    "Data4",
    "Data5",
    "Data6",
    "Data7",
    "Data8",
    "Data9",
    "Data10",
    "Data11",
    "Data12",
    "Data13",
  ],
  titleText: "Source",
  color: "#91CF52",
};

const panelData = {
  count: [3, 4, 6, 2, 4],
  categories: ["Data1", "Data2", "Data3", "Data4", "Data5"],
  titleText: "Panel Contribution",
  color: "#52CFCF",
};

const podData = {
  count: [3, 2, 3, 1],
  categories: ["2-3 yrs", "4-6 yrs", "6-8 yrs", "10+ yrs"],
  titleText: "POD Coverage",
  color: "#5291CF",
};

const companyData = {
  count: [2, 4, 5, 2, 1, 5],
  categories: [
    "Data1",
    "Data2",
    "Data3",
    "Data4",
    "Data5",
    "Data6",
  ],
  titleText: "Hired from",
  color: "#CF52CF",
};

const drawerWidth = 340;
const open = true;

const Main = styled("main", { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "open" })(
  ({ theme, open }) => ({
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    marginLeft: `-${drawerWidth}px`,
    ...(open && {
      transition: theme.transitions.create("margin", {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
      }),
      marginLeft: 0,
    }),
  })
);

const DrawerHeader = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
  // necessary for content to be below app bar
  ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  justifyContent: "flex-end",
}));

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <Main open={open}>
      <DrawerHeader />
      <StackedChart />
      <br />
      <br />
      <div style={{ marginTop: "100px", display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap",rowGap: "250px", coulmnGap:"100px"}}>
        <BarChart data={roleData} style={{ padding: "200px" }} />
        <BarChart data={spocData} />
        <BarChart data={sourceData} />
        <BarChart data={panelData} />
        <BarChart data={podData} />
        <BarChart data={companyData} />
      </div>
    </Main>
  );
};

const CandidateForm = () => {
  return (
    <Main open={open}>
      <DrawerHeader />
      <NewCandidateForm />
     {/* <h1>Test</h1> */}
     
    </Main>
  );
};

const Logout = () => {
  return (
    <Main open={open}>
      <DrawerHeader />
      <h1>Logout</h1>
    </Main>
  );
};

const Routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    sidebarName: "Dashboard",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/candidate",
    sidebarName: "Candidate",
    component: CandidateForm,
  },
  {
    path: "/logout",
    sidebarName: "Logout",
    component: Logout,
  },
];

export default Routes;
```

When I tried to switch component in the above code with a h1 tag (that has been commented out), the nav bar works fine. Wonder if there's a problem in the candidate form code that breaks the UI in the left pane.

Any help in debugging the issue will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find out the reason behind the nav bar stacking up together for the particular route. It was because the Button component in MUI was trying to override the drawer component. Now, instead of the Button component, I used the vanilla  element and the nav bar on the left is no more breaking for the candidate route.